# trainHog opencv sample assert positive count <labels.size

Tags: opencv

i am trying to train inria dataset using trainHog opencv example, and i'm getting the assert there, what i'm doing wrong?

```
clog << "Histogram of Gradients are being calculated for negative images...";
    computeHOGs(pos_image_size, neg_lst, gradient_lst, flip_samples);
    size_t negative_count = gradient_lst.size() - positive_count;
    labels.insert(labels.end(), negative_count, -1);
    CV_Assert(positive_count < labels.size());
```

Comment: the error message looks like there are less positive samples (images) than labels. Make sure you provide the right input and make sure that all images (or whatever input you use) were loaded correctly.

Comment: yes, i was having wrong parameters for images, but now i have another problem when loading the negative images(putting them into a vector of matrix) it gets stuck to image 9999 i dont know why, and second time i tried i received an error about matrix, out of memory that i couldnt catch it again. I'm thinking if is about that i have almost 118000 negative picture? and how i could solve this @Micka

Comment: can you try with less negative samples and increase until you get errors?

Comment: i tried with 8000 but still it gets blocked on loading the images on filesize-1 can t understand.

Comment: and is a little dificult to debug while i have so many images, i tried with an if in my function when he gets with the if there but after he passes it he gets blocked again, if i have around 2000 positive how many negative should i have? i can t understand what i m doing wrong. this one being an opencv sample

Comment: sorry, I don't have much experience with trainHog. Maybe some of your images are broken.